# Simulate a UIButton Click event using code

Tags: ios

How to simulate physical touch on UIButton using code? what I want is the UIButton changes to a hightlight state and then back to normal state again like it's been clicked by a real finger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply achieve by:

```
- (void)buttonTapped {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{

        [_button setHighlighted:YES];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [_button sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        // or call the relevant method here

        [_button setHighlighted:NO];
    }];
}
```

where you can see the hilighting animation too...

Answer (score 4):

```
[button sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [**KIF**](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF).

**KIF** (“Keep it Functional”), is an open-source user interface testing framework. You’ll be able to write tests that simulate user input, like touches, swipes and text entry. These tests give your apps an automated, real-world user interface workout.

Here is a **Ray Wenderlich** tutorial by **Greg Heo** [iOS UI Testing with KIF](http://www.raywenderlich.com/61419/ios-ui-testing-with-kif)

After installation simulating an `UIButton` tap is as easy as

```
[tester tapViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"Clear"];
```